# Managing Mutations Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Is this correct way of managing mutations?

My HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                      <label>Merchant Id No:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" v-model="merchantId">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Name:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" v-model="merchantName">
                  </div>
```

My Computed Properties:

```
 merchantId: {
          get(){

              return this.merchant.merchant_id
          }, 
          set(value){

            this.$store.commit('merchantId', value);
          }
      },
      merchantName: {
          get(){

            return this.merchant.name
          },
          set(value){
            this.$store.commit('merchantName', value);
          }
      },
```

My Mutations:

```
merchantName(state, merchantName){
            state.merchant.name = merchantName
        },
        merchantId(state, merchantId){
            state.merchant.merchant_id = merchantId
        },
```

Is there a way to mutate only in the merchant? Because I need to do it one by one.

```
merchant(state, merchant){
        state.merchant = merchant
    },
```

Here is my merchant Object.

[image]

Comment: `Is there a way to mutate only in the merchant?`, could not understand your question completely.

Comment: Thanks. This is how merchant mutate `merchant(state, merchant){
        state.merchant = merchant
    },` my question is there a way I don't individually create a mutation for every field... example `merchant.name` was changed.. then how can I do it by not using `merchantName: {
          get(){

            return this.merchant.name
          },
          set(value){
            this.$store.commit('merchantName', value);
          }
      },`

Comment: The problem is I need to do it every `merchant.name`, `merchant.merchant_id` and so on...

Comment: ok , got it.... since you are using computed setter for each `v-model` you can't commit once mutation updating your `merchant` object in the state... you can add a button and set click listener to it which commit a a mutation with `merchanr` obj as its payload

Comment: How to do it? Just a sample... Thanks.

Comment: added an example as answer have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a button at the end of your input fields and add a click listener to commit a mutation withe the payload of merchant object.

**Example**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Merchant Id No:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" v-model="merchant.merchantId">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" v-model="merchant.merchantName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control border-input" v-model="merchant.merchantEmail">
</div>

// more input fields...

<button @click.prevent="save">Save merchant<button>
```

**script**

```
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            merchant:{
                merchantId:'',
                merchantName:'',
                merchantEmail:''
                //more properties binded to the v-model
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        click(){
            this.$store.commit('merchant', this.merchant);
        }
    }
}
```

And your mutation

```
merchant(state, merchant){
        state.merchant = merchant
    },
```